# Functional equation for ray class zeta functions

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory

I understand that there is a functional equation for ideal class zeta functions of number fields.  That is, if $k$ is a number field and $C$ is a class of fractional ideals of $k$, then

$\zeta_C(s) = \sum_{\substack{\mathfrak{a} \in C\\ \mathfrak{a} \text{ integral}}} \frac{1}{N(\mathfrak{a})^s}$

has a functional equation relating $\zeta_C(s)$ to $\zeta_C(s-1)$ (I guess this is in Neukirch, *Algebraic Number Theory*, Chapter VII).  Does such a functional equation exist for general ray class zeta functions, where $C$ is replaced by a ray class modulo some modulus?  I am especially interested in when the modulus includes some infinite places, i.e., for "narrow ideal class zeta functions".

(I guess that maybe the answer is yes, since Hurwitz zeta functions satisfy a functional equation, at least for a limited range of $s$.)

Comment: You need to be careful when there are infinitely many units in $\mathcal{O}_K$ (when $K$ is not imaginary quadratic). In that case you have $\zeta_C(s) = \alpha \beta^{s}\sum_{ a \in I / \mathcal{O}_K^\times} N(a)^{-s}$ where $I$ is an ideal of $\mathcal{O}_K$ inverse of $C$ in the class group. Do you know a simple proof of its functional equation ? I have [this reference](http://kskedlaya.org/Math254B/zetafunction.pdf) and Neukrich, the others I think use the Poisson summation formula in the adeles ring.

Comment: Then we should be able to prove that $\sum_{ a \in I / \mathcal{O}_K^\times} \chi(a) N(a)^{-s}$ has a similar functional equation for many characters $\chi$ modulo $\mathfrak{M}$ and we'll get the functional equation for $\sum_{ a \in I / \mathcal{O}_K^\times, a \equiv d \bmod \mathfrak{M}} N(a)^{-s}$

Comment: I was thinking something like what you suggest may work -- or at least, I was thinking an appropriate linear combination of Hecke L-functions would do the trick. But then I was a little worried about some things: 1) In Theorem 8.5 of Chapter VII of Neukirch, the Grossencharactere must be primitive; 2) in the same theorem, the $W(\chi)$ (the root number) depends on the conductor of the character

Comment: I thought maybe these things would be incompatible for the various characters we use to form a linear combination

Comment: You should be able to reduce non-primitive characters to primitive characters with a term $\prod_{\mathfrak{p} | M} (1-\chi(\mathfrak{p}) N(\mathfrak{p})^{-s})$ in the same way as for Dirichlet L-functions

Comment: But it seems to me these extra factors might be different for the different L-functions in the linear combination, just as their root numbers may be

Comment: Yes that's what you need to check. It will be easier I'd say if you can re-prove everything, for example starting with $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ whose class group is $(1), (2,1+\sqrt{-5})$ (you can adapt [p.9 here](http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/mfms/notes_c/analytic_continuations.pdf)). $\displaystyle\zeta_{\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]}(s) = \frac{1}{4}\sum_{(n,m) \in \mathbb{Z}^2\setminus(0,0)} |n+\sqrt{-5}m|^{-2s}+\frac{2^s}{4}\sum_{(n,m) \in \mathbb{Z}^2\setminus(0,0)} | 2n+(1+\sqrt{-5}) m|^{-2s}$ where $\frac14$ is because there are $4$ units

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @user1952009 commented, yes, with characters with the same conductor (and maybe same sign/epsilon factor in functional equation), linear combinations obviously inherit the functional equation.

For example, for not-narrow ideal classes, all the Hecke L-functions have the same functional equation, so arbitrary linear combinations inherit it, and the "ideal class zeta" you wrote is such a linear combination (by the usual Fourier inversion on the finite abelian group that is the class group).

A superficial thought experiment makes me think that the narrow-class-group characters all give L-functions with the same functional equation, too.

For general ray-class things not all characters will give L-functions with the same functional equation, so $\zeta_C(1-s)$ will be a messier linear combination of $\Lambda(1-s,\chi)$'s.

Comment: Haha, the question was up for hours, and I posted my comments with these same concerns almost at the same time as when you posted your answer.  I'll think about this more -- I was just hoping for a reference that works out exactly when everything works out (so I don't have to think to hard, and maybe incorrectly :-) )

Comment: @BarrySmith Paul's website is indeed a good reference  http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/mfms/

Comment: There may not be any visible reference for your precise question, because I think the standard sources would be almost exclusively interested in going in the other direction, namely, in piecing together zeta functions and L-functions from ideal-class contributions. From a more modern viewpoint, adelic Fourier transform and Iwasawa-Tate give a precise description of what happens to ray-class zetas under $s\to 1-s$, with not much room for ambiguity.

Comment: @user1952009 Wow, his website is quite extensive.  Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @ PaulGarrett, @BarrySmith : To continue [on p.9 there](http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/mfms/notes_c/analytic_continuations.pdf) I wrote the functional equation for $\zeta_K(s), K = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$ whose ideal class group has $2$ elements http://www.paris8.free.fr/Zeta_Riemann/functional_equation_dedekind_zeta_function_by_ideal_class.html